# Why can't the <li> label width be set to 100px?

Tags: html, css

Here's what I'm trying to make:
    [image]

The above table was accomplished by using the `table` tag, and each `td` in the table was set to have a width of 100px.

```
<html>    
<header>    
<meta charset="gbk" />    
<style type="text/css">    
div.whole {    
     padding: 200px 0 0 0;    
     border:2px solid red;    
     width:600px;    
     margin:0 auto;    
     align:center;}    
p.h {width:600px;text-align:center;}    
td{    
    width:100px;    
    border-bottom: 1px dashed black;}    
</style>    
</header>    


<body>    
<div class="whole">    
<p class='h'>Ò»ÖÜ¿Î³Ì±í</p>    
<table>    
<tr>    
<td>Ê±Œä/ÐÇÆÚ</td><td>ÖÜÒ»</td><td>ÖÜ¶þ</td><td>ÖÜÈý</td><td>ÖÜËÄ</td><td>ÖÜÎå</td>    
</tr>    
<tr>    
<td>9:00</td><td>Ó¢Óï</td><td>ÓïÎÄ</td><td>ÎÞ</td><td>ÌåÓý</td><td>ÊýÑ§</td>    
</tr>    
<tr>    
<td>10:00</td><td>ÎÞ</td><td>ÌåÓý</td><td>Ó¢Óï</td><td>ÌåÓý</td><td>ÊýÑ§</td>    
</tr>    
<tr>    
<td>11:00</td><td>ÎÞ</td><td>ÌåÓý</td><td>Ó¢Óï</td><td>ÌåÓý</td><td>ÊýÑ§</td>    
</tr>    
<tr>    
<td>12:00</td><td>Ó¢Óï</td><td>Ó¢Óï</td><td>ÊýÑ§</td><td>ÓïÎÄ</td><td>ÎÞ</td>    
</tr>    

<tr>    
<td>×Ü¿ÎÊ±</td><td>2</td><td>4</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>3</td>    
</tr>    
</table>    
</div>    
</body>    
</html>
```

I'm trying to achieve the same displayed effect with li table.

```
   <html>
<header>
<meta charset="gbk" />
<style type="text/css">
div.whole {
     padding: 200px 0 0 0;
     border:2px solid red;
     width:600px;
     margin:0 auto;
     align:center;}
p.h {width:600px;text-align:center;}
li{ display:inline;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed black;
    width:100px;}
</style>
</header>

<body>
<div class="whole">
<p class='h'>Ò»ÖÜ¿Î³Ì±í</p>

<ul>
<li>Ê±Œä/ÐÇÆÚ</li><li>ÖÜÒ»</li><li>ÖÜ¶þ</li><li>ÖÜÈý</li><li>ÖÜËÄ</li><li>ÖÜÎå</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>9:00</li><li>Ó¢Óï</li><li>ÓïÎÄ</li><li>ÎÞ</li><li>ÌåÓý</li><li>ÊýÑ§</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>10:00</li><li>ÎÞ</li><li>ÌåÓý</li><li>Ó¢Óï</li><li>ÌåÓý</li><li>ÊýÑ§</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>11:00</li><li>ÎÞ</li><li>ÌåÓý</li><li>Ó¢Óï</li><li>ÌåÓý</li><li>ÊýÑ§</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>12:00</li><li>Ó¢Óï</li><li>Ó¢Óï</li><li>ÊýÑ§</li><li>ÓïÎÄ</li><li>ÎÞ</li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li>×Ü¿ÎÊ±</li><li>2</li><li>4</li><li>3</li><li>4</li><li>3</li>
</ul>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The displayed effect is
    [image]

Why can't `li` tags be set to 100px? What other approaches could I use to get the same formatting result?
To set the inline-block as gibberish say ,the css codes changed.

```
<html>
<header>
<meta charset="gbk" />
<style type="text/css">
div.whole {
     padding: 200px 0 0 0;
     border:2px solid red;
     width:660px;
     margin:0 auto;
     align:center;}
p.h {width:660px;text-align:center;}
li{ list-style:none;
    margin:0 0;
    padding 0 0 0 0;
    display:inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed black;
    width:100px;}
</style>
</header>

<body>
<div class="whole">
<p class='h'>Ò»ÖÜ¿Î³Ì±í</p>

<ul>
<li>Ê±¼ä/ÐÇÆÚ</li><li>ÖÜÒ»</li><li>ÖÜ¶þ</li><li>ÖÜÈý</li><li>ÖÜËÄ</li><li>ÖÜÎå</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>9:00</li><li>Ó¢Óï</li><li>ÓïÎÄ</li><li>ÎÞ</li><li>ÌåÓý</li><li>ÊýÑ§</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>10:00</li><li>ÎÞ</li><li>ÌåÓý</li><li>Ó¢Óï</li><li>ÌåÓý</li><li>ÊýÑ§</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>11:00</li><li>ÎÞ</li><li>ÌåÓý</li><li>Ó¢Óï</li><li>ÌåÓý</li><li>ÊýÑ§</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>12:00</li><li>Ó¢Óï</li><li>Ó¢Óï</li><li>ÊýÑ§</li><li>ÓïÎÄ</li><li>ÎÞ</li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li>×Ü¿ÎÊ±</li><li>2</li><li>4</li><li>3</li><li>4</li><li>3</li>
</ul>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The displayed effect is as the following:
[image]

Now how to delete the blank at the beginning and end of line?To make the two css  totally same  displayed effect?
[image]

Comment: Any element can be made to display like any other element, but you need to set the "display" property appropriately and you may also (as in this case) need to unset/override default padding/margin for that element.

Comment: You posted both code same by mistake. Please correct it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inline elements cannot set width.  set the elements to inline-block:

[jsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8tLmswbc/)

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li{width:80px;list-style:none;text-align:center;border:1px solid grey;}
/*  li{display:inline;}  */
li{display:inline-block;}  /*  comment out */
```

Comment: To fix my css as you say,still one more problem remain,how to delete the blank at the beginning and end of line?

Answer (score 1):

add label to  `display:inline-block`

```
label{display:inline-block;}
```